# How to transform graph in Python

Tags: python, math, graph

I currently have two different sets of graphs.

One graph goes from, (100,100) to (174,200)

And the other graph goes from (560, 544) to (649,631)

Using the distance formula, they both have around the same distance, but they have different slopes

For the graph going from (560, 544) to (649,631), I have some of the points going in between and it is not a straight line.

I do not have any of the point between (100,100) to (174,200).

I want to mimic the path of (560, 544) to (649,631) except I want the starting point to be (100,100) and the ending point to be (174,200).

These are the points I have in between

[http://i.imgur.com/ZlBbgEh.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E75kf.png)

This is the code I have written in python right now

```
with open(file[0], newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(int(row[0]) - 460, int(row[1]) - 444, duration=float(row[2]))
```

This makes the starting point (100,100) but does not change the ending point.

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: So you want to do a transformation on the data that moves the start point from (560, 544) to (100, 100)? and then end point to (189, 187)? Or does the end point need to be (174,200)?

Comment: @DerekHalden I believe the OP wants the later, as the former is what he already achieved.

Comment: I want to perform a transformation to make the start point (100,100) and the end point (174,200). But eventually, the starting and ending point will vary. But the distance will always be around 124 pixels

Comment: @Błotosmętek Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized version of Derek Halden's code - works for any data:

```
with open(file[0], newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    points = [ tuple(map(float, row)) for row in reader ]
old_start_x, old_start_y = points[0][0:2] # first point
old_end_x, old_end_y = points[-1][0:2]    # last point
new_start_x, new_start_y, new_end_x, new_end_y =  100, 100, 174, 200
for x, y, d in points:
    print( new_start_x + (x - old_start_x)*(new_end_x-new_start_x)/(old_end_x-old_start_x),
           new_start_y + (y - old_start_y)*(new_end_y-new_start_y)/(old_end_y-old_start_y),
           d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the following is what you want:

```
with open(file[0], newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print((int(row[0]) - 560)*(74/87) + 100, (int(row[1]) - 544)*(100/89) + 100, duration=float(row[2]))
```

Basically, you need to scale it to fit in the bounds of the problem.
If you had all of the points in both graphs start at (0,0) you would need to scale it by a multiple of 74/87, to get to to an endpoint of 87 from an endpoint of 74.
and 100/89 to get to an endpoint of 100 from 89. Afterwards you need to shift up by 100 back to where everything started.

Comment: Using this, the points I get are
(83, 112)
(108, 159)
(136, 188)
(156, 208)
(157, 210). So the starting and ending are incorrect

Comment: Yeah, I made a couple of mathematical errors at the beginning. I didn't get the factors right exactly, and I forgot to adjust for the fact that you wanted to start at 100,100

Comment: Try with the new one.

Comment: Oh wow! This actually makes so much sense. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!